# Can't access my public IP outside of the country

Tags: ip, arch-linux, home-server, lighttpd

Even a month ago everything was working fine, but recently I found out that my Public IP is no longer accessible outside my country. https://fahimscirex.duckdns.org is the link attached to my public ip. I've talked to my ISP, but they couldn't clarify anything.

Is changing the provider only solution here?

Comment: That DNS name resolves to 103.199.235.71 which is pingable from The Netherlands. According to various geo-location services that IP-address is in Bangladesh. It would help if you clarified (you can EDIT that into your question) which country(s) you mean with "no longer accessible outside my own country", because it is certainly not "all countries" were this happens. Sound more as if the country (or ISP) you are experiencing the block has a firewall in place (in which case your own ISP can do nothing about it).

Comment: See https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/fahimscirex.duckdns.org

Comment: @Tonny I've checked USA, CANADA, ENGLAND and some other countries. And yes you're right, ip seems to be accessible from China, so it's not all the countries.